# Callback telegram бот

Tags: php, telegram-bot, бот

Всем привет. Учусь делать чат-ботов. Вопрос: почему не передается Callback при нажатии на inline кнопки? Что я делаю не так?

```
$chat_id = $result["message"]["chat"]["id"];

$keyboard = Keyboard::make()
->inline()
->row(
    Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Show menu', 'callback_data' => 'show_menu']),
    Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Request price', 'callback_data' => 'requiest.price'])        
);
$response = $telegram->sendMessage([
'chat_id' => $chat_id, 
'text' => 'Hello',
'reply_markup' => $keyboard
]);
$result = $telegram->getWebhookUpdate();
if ($result->isType('callback_query')) {
    $query = $result->getCallbackQuery();
    $data  = $query->getData();
    $chid = $query->getFrom()->getId();
    $json = json_decode($query->getMessage(), true);
    $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chid, 'text' => 'Here is callback', 'reply_markup' => $keyboard ]);

} else {
    $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => 'Callback is not found here']);
}
```

Comment: вроде всё верно внешне

Comment: @Anatol изменился API у telegram, теперь версия 2.0 telegram-bot-sdk работает не совсем правильно.

Comment: в таком случае лучше обратиться к разработчикам *telegram-bot-sdk* и завести issue, поскольку API не изменился, а расширился

Comment: @Anatol уже сделано)